# What's meaning of ベシュワー and ３つくらい (there is an image)

Tags: translation, meaning

[image]

I can guess that **３つくらい** its meaning something like "3 of something" But what's it "something" in this sentence? Floors? Or house?
And I don't know anything about **ベシュワー**, but I can guess that it's sound when using a spray?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, it's ブシュワー

Answer (score 1):

Peshuu~ is like 'Psshhhhhsh' sound coming out from a can.  And 3つ might be みっつ japanese counting of 3. As in ひとつ、ふたつ、みっつ、etc.

くらい Is approximately, so the meaning of 3つくらい is 'approximately three (things) '

Comment: I understand about peshuu, but I don't quite understand about ３つくらい...Such the third of? 
こんなのを３つくら

Comment: I understand that くらい it's meaning "about". But I'm confused because こんなを
こんなーsuch.
Here such third? I can't understand what it meant.

Comment: Or it maybe meaning "Such houses about 3, made of 3 colors, the colors are red, blue and yellow." Someone help me Q__Q

Comment: Or it's the third house and the colors of this house it's red, blue and yellow.

Comment: @Alai i can't read all the text since the picture is quite small and so doesn't quite understand the context. But it seems the こんなを3つくらい roughly means : this house here use around three pieces of wood part that you made and color previously with aerosol paint.

Comment: You are right, こんなの means "something like this" (=こんなもの), so they're saying that they made about three houses (= red, blue, and yellow houses) that looked like the one in the picture.